# Sign user in upon account creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I'm using the [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) module and the [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gems.

The default behavior seems to be that when a user registers, the user gets sent an email with a confirmation link. I don't want this behavior; I just want the user to immediately be signed in following account creation, which is of course a really common way for account creation to work.

I'm so unsure how to achieve this that I don't even know what to ask. Would anyone happen to have used these libraries before who can provide some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason, your answer is mostly correct. You will also need to instruct the server to bypass the email confirmation step. If this isn't done, the user won't be able to sign in until the link in the confirmation email has been visited. Here are the complete instructions:

### 1. Bypass email confirmation server-side

Assuming the model is called `User`, run the `skip_confirmation!` method as a pre-create callback. This really just sets the user's `confirmed_at` value to the current time, but the step is necessary to bypass email confirmation.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  before_create :skip_confirmation!
end
```

### 2. Sign in immediately after successful registration

Assuming the html form looks like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submitRegistration(registrationForm)" role="form" ng-init="registrationForm = {}">
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label>email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="registrationForm.email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="registrationForm.password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>password confirmation</label>
      <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="registrationForm.password_confirmation" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

**Update** - as of devise_token_auth version 0.1.29.beta2, users will be automatically authenticated upon registration if the above `before_create :skip_confirmation!` callback is used. So the above code is all that is necessary.

Comment: Is this still the correct answer?

I am also trying to disable email confirmation. Right now I am getting an undefined method error for `:skip_confirmation!`

I removed that line from my `User` model, and tested registration, validate_token, password_reset, and sign_in for that user, and never had to actually set a `:confirmed_at` value. It looks like things may have changed?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the answer to my own question (natch).

I modified my controller to look like this:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name lunchHubApp.controller:UserRegistrationsCtrl
 * @description
 * # UserRegistrationsCtrl
 * Controller of the lunchHubApp
 */
angular.module('lunchHubApp')
  .controller('UserRegistrationsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$auth', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $auth) {
    $scope.handleRegBtnClick = function() {
      $auth.submitRegistration($scope.registrationForm)
        .then(function() { 
          $auth.submitLogin({
            email: $scope.registrationForm.email,
            password: $scope.registrationForm.password
          });
        });
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: did you submitRegistration promise resolve in this scenario? Mine doesn't seem to resolve